# Hover with absolute position in Safari

Tags: safari, hover, absolute

I have some text, that changes into an editable textfield on click. The text is coming from the database. The overflow is hidden.

On hover I want all the hidden text to be visible. I'm using `span:hover {position:absolute}`. It works perfectly on IE, Chrome, FF – but not in Safari. I removed absolute positioning and added `background-color` to see if Safari reacts to hover at all. It worked, the background color changed. But when I put absolute positioning back on, Safari doesn't react to the hover.

Comment: can you make a fiddle and show some code?

Comment: Even this simple hover is not working in Safari because of absolute positioning. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fmzv6/3/

Comment: Which version of safari and OS you use? For me on Safari 6.1.3  and mac... worked fine...

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

In this way worked on Windows 7 and Safari 5.1.x and in most browser:

HTML:

```
<span  class="hover">Belekas</span>
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.hover:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fmzv6/6/)